# How do I remove a curve from a plt plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

At the moment, I have a histogram with a curve sitting on top of it (kind of like a fit) and I want to update this curve by changing some parameters. At the moment, whenever I update the curve, the plot just draws another curve. So, how do I delete the old curve?

An example of this would be as follow:

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x2 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ln1 = plt.plot(x1,y)
ln2 = plt.plot(x2,y)
```

This code would produce two parrallel lines. So, let's say that I want to remove ln1. How would I do that?

There is another post that is similar to this, but none of the answers seem to work for me. I have tried these but they do not work:

ln1.remove()

ax.lines.remove(ln1)

Comment: You could just create a new plot repeating everything but the undesired lines.  You could also use `set_data` or `set_xdata` as `ln1[0].set_xdata([2,2,4,4,6])`.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ln1` is not the line object itself but a list of lines. If you want to delete the line object, you first have to get it

```
line = ln1[0]
```

delete it

```
line.remove()
```

and then redraw the figure (potentially):

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

If you just want to change the values, @JohanC suggestion to use `line.set_data(x3, y)` is probably the computationally fastest way to do it.